# Skip nil:NilClass if no value is returned

Tags: ruby

I have this hash with which I sue to store a lot of codes:

```
system_errors = {
  '00' => {error_class: SuccessfulResponse, error_message: 'TESTMODE'},
  ...
}

error = system_errors[response_code]
error[:error_class].new(error[:error_message], technical_message, response_code)
```

But when there is no match, I get:

```
`parse_response': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I avoid this error? Apparently I want to skip if there is no match.

Comment: What does "parse_response" refer to ?

Comment: This is the name of the method where the above code is located.

Comment: The error is coming from somewhere outside of what you wrote here.

Comment: How are you calling `parse_response` ? Also, what do you expect the output to be when there is no match ?

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: What you mean by "skip"? Skip what? What do you want when there is no match?

Comment: I have to correct myself - I need to skip new object initialization there is no matched value.

Comment: What do you want to get instead? Notice that Ruby always returns a value.

Comment: for example `puts 'skipping test'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if error = system_errors[response_code]
  error[:error_class].new(error[:error_message], technical_message, response_code)
else
  puts 'skipping test'
end
```

Notice that this returns an instance (likely an error object, judging from the name), not raise it, in case there is a match, which is what you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

***NB** this answer is given for the sake of future readers.*

The proper way to go would be to define a default hash element for non-existing keys:

```
system_errors = (Hash.new do |h, k|
  h[k] = {error_class: StandardError,
          error_message: "Undefined error code: #{k}"}
end).merge(
  '00' => {error_class: SuccessfulResponse,
           error_message: 'TESTMODE'},
  ...
)
```

And use it as you’ve used already. On inexisting error it will return the default value.

Comment: I.e., the null object pattern.

Comment: @sawa at some extent, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
error = system_errors[response_code]
if error
  error[:error_class].new(error[:error_message], technical_message, response_code) 
else
  puts "Found no ErrorClass"
end
```

That should take care of not creating an object if no error class is found. Notice the `if` condition at the end of the object initialization line. It will return `true` if you find an error with the provided key else return `nil`, which is equal to a `false` in ruby.

Comment: How I can print some text if there is no value?

Comment: I've updated the answer